# How do I specify database connection parameters using the RUBBER EC2 ruby / rails deployment tool?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-ec2, cloud-hosting

I'm setting up an instance on ec2 using the rubber deployment tool. I need to determine where I specify the database connection parameters.

In the `/config/rubber/common/database.yml` file, I see this code that is used to create the `/config/database.yml` file for the instance I'm deploying to:

```
<%
   @path = "#{RUBBER_ROOT}/config/database.yml"
%>
<%= RUBBER_ENV %>:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: <%= rubber_env.db_name %>
  username: <%= rubber_env.db_user %>
  password: <%= rubber_env.db_pass %>
  host: <%= rubber_instances.for_role('db', 'primary' => true).first.full_name %>
  pool: 5
```

But there's nowhere I can find where it documents where I should put the values `db_name`, `d_user` and `db_pass`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those values are set in config/rubber/rubber-mysql.yml